# DataTables filter selects are off by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using the jquery [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net) library for sprucing up a table, and am having some problems with the filtering selects showing up in the wrong place.

The issue is that I am using the `'filter'` class on the `th` elements to specify if a column should filtered. however, if I skip one column the rest come out of order.

So in the below (using DataTables example data) [and in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/42GrL/), Position is not filtered, while Name, Office and Age are, however, the `select` above Office has Positions, and the `select` above Age has Offices.

[image]

The problematic code I'm using is below, but its [heavily based on the DataTables filtering example](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) and I can't seem to get the selects to line up properly if I skip one.

```
var table = $('#nhpaCompare').DataTable({
    "paging": false,
    "columnDefs": [ {
        "targets": noOrdering ,
        "orderable": false // defined elsewhere
    } ]

});

$("#nhpaCompare thead tr th.filter").each( function ( i ) {

    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
        .appendTo( $(this).empty() )
        .on( 'change', function () {
            table.column( i )
                .search( ''+$(this).val()+'')
                .draw();
        } );

    table.column( i ).data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
        select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
    } );

} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't you know it I went to all that trouble, and tried one last thing...

The `i` in the `.each()` call is just the number of the iteration through, not a number that corresponds to the actual column. So where I though I would be `0,2,3` it was actual `0,1,2`.

So this:

```
$("#nhpaCompare thead tr th.filter").each( function ( i ) {
    ...
} );
```

Should be this instead:

```
$("#nhpaCompare thead tr:first th").each( function ( i ) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("filter")) {
        ...
    }
} );
```

[It works fine in jsFiddle now.](http://jsfiddle.net/3CGP6/1/)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to add one if condition to check if th has class filter and jQuery would be like

```
$("#nhpaCompare thead tr:first th").each( function ( i ) {

    if ($(this).hasClass("filter")) {       
        var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
            .appendTo( $(this).empty() )
            .on( 'change', function () {
                table.column( i )
                    .search( ''+$(this).val()+'')
                    .draw();
            } );

        table.column( i ).data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
            select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
        } );
    }
    } );
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/42GrL/3/)**

Comment: Yeah I figured that out :/ Thanks though :)